# SQL - Combine columns from two tables with condition

Tags: sql, db2

I have two tables like:

```
Table A             Table B

+---------------+   +------------------------------+    
| ID   NAME     |   | ID    TYPE       DATE        |    
+---------------+   +------------------------------+    
| 001    A      |   | 001    URGE     2024-01-01   |    
| 002    B      |   | 001    UPDATE   2024-01-02   |
| 003    C      |   | 001    URGE     2024-01-03   |
+---------------+   | 002    UPDATE   2023-12-30   |
                    +------------------------------+
```

I want to select the all the results in Table A and join table B with condition "TYPE = 'URGE'" and output the most recent DATE, otherwise the DATE column output "-".

I have tried the code like:

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.NAME,
    CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'URGE' THEN B.TYPE ELSE '-' END AS TYPE,
    CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'URGE' THEN B.DATE ELSE NULL END AS DATE
FROM
    TableA A
LEFT JOIN
    TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.TYPE = 'URGE';
```

The result is:

```
   +-------------------------------------+    
   | ID    NAME   TYPE       DATE        |    
   +-------------------------------------+    
   | 001    A    URGE     2024-01-01     | 
   | 001    A    URGE     2024-01-03     |   
   | 002    B    -        NULL           |
   | 003    C    -        NULL           |
   +-------------------------------------+
```

Buy my expected result is:

```
   +-------------------------------------+    
   | ID    NAME   TYPE       DATE        |    
   +-------------------------------------+    
   | 001    A    URGE     2024-01-03     |    
   | 002    B    -        NULL           |
   | 003    C    -        NULL           |
   +-------------------------------------+
```

How should I change the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to aggregate the result based on date -

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.NAME,
    CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'URGE' THEN B.TYPE ELSE '-' END AS TYPE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'URGE' THEN B.DATE ELSE NULL END) AS DATE
FROM
    TableA A
LEFT JOIN
    TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.TYPE = 'URGE'
GROUP BY A.ID,
         A.NAME,
         CASE WHEN B.TYPE = 'URGE' THEN B.TYPE ELSE '-' END AS TYPE;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `NOT EXISTS` and `LEFT JOIN` as follows:

```
SELECT
    A.ID,
    A.NAME,
    COALESCE(B.TYPE, '-') AS TYPE,
    B.DATE AS DATE
FROM
    TableA A
LEFT JOIN
    TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.TYPE = 'URGE'
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      (SELECT 1 FROM TableB BB 
        WHERE B.ID = BB.ID AND B.TYPE = BB.TYPE
          AND BB.DATE > B.DATE);
```

Also, Note that you don't need `CASE..WHEN` in the `SELECT` expression.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem then you can accept the answer to mark your question as resolved.